# Comparing two types of lists in Python

Tags: python, list

I have two lists `J` and `Cond`. I want to compare these lists and print corresponding values in `J` for `False` in `Cond`. Is there equivalent of `np.where()`? I present the expected output.

```
J=[[1,2,4,6,7]]
Cond = [False, True, False, True, False]
```

The expected output is

```
J=[1,4,7]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do:

```
[j for j, cond in zip(J[0], Cond) if not cond]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `zip` builtin:

```py
J = [zipped_val[0] for zipped_val in zip(J[0], Cond) if not(zipped_val[1])]
print(J)
```

Which results in:

```
[1, 4, 7]
```